# Why is JPA entity manager resulting in duplicate key value errors using glassfish?

Tags: postgresql, jpa, glassfish, java-ee-6

I currently have about 3 messages from a JMS client sending to a MDB every few seconds. The MDB is using a JPA entity manager to persist the data to PostgreSQL. This works fine for about a minute or so.

Then the problem becomes this message ...

```
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence
Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461):org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseExcep
tion Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value
violates unique constraint "scan_pkey"
Detail: Key (id)=(984) already exists.
Error Code: 0
Call: INSERT INTO Scan (id, th, ag, dl) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?
)
    bind => [11 parameters bound]
```

Heres my Scan entity.

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name="scanIdGen", initialValue=1000, sequenceName="scan_seq")
@Table(name="Scan")
public class Scan implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="scanIdGen")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="th")
    private Integer th;

    @Column(name="ag")
    private Integer ag;

    @Column(name="dl")
    private Integer dl;

    // ...
}
```

And here's the database schema.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE scan_seq START 1000;
CREATE TABLE Scan (
    id       INTEGER DEFAULT NEXTVAL('scan_seq') PRIMARY KEY    
    th       INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
    ag       INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
    dl       INTEGER DEFAULT NULL
);
```

Another seemingly not so big problem is that my primary keys don't really start at 1000, but usually at 950. Don't know why.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a guess Glassfish/EclipseLink expects the default sequence increment of 50 specified (for some insane reason) by the JPA standard. Your PostgreSQL sequence defaults to an increment of 1.

Specify an `allocationSize` of 1 in your `@SequenceGenerator`, eg:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name="scanIdGen", sequenceName="scan_seq", allocationSize=1)
```

or use the `IDENTITY` generation strategy.

Comment: I did remove the allocationSize so that it defaults to 50, but no difference. I still get the duplicate key error.

Comment: @user1718761 EclipseLink has probably inserted values that're higher than the highest sequence currently in the DB. You'll probably need to bump the sequence up to match the data that's been inserted. `BEGIN; LOCK TABLE Scan; SELECT setval(scan_seq, (SELECT max(id) FROM Scan)+1); COMMIT;`.

Comment: I found out that everytime the keys reach the point where they hit about 1000, then I get duplicate key errors. So I don't understand these two things.  

1. Why are the keys starting at about 950, sometimes 951, sometimes 952 when I specifically state START 1000 when creating the tables and sequences.  

2. I did try GenerationType.IDENTITY and it made no difference.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. I added the allocationSize back to the @SequenceGenerator with 1 to match the database sequence increment size. All is well. Big thanks.